# HTML5: Button link is not working

Tags: html

I'm wondering why my button is not working, this is my code:

```
<button type="button" a href="#dos">CONOCÉ SOBRE SU VIDA</button>
```

`#dos` is supposed to be an anchor tag with an id. What is it that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Could you try: `<a href="#dos">CONOCÉ SOBRE SU VIDA</a>`?

Comment: An anchor is a link, declared with an `<a></a>` tag. You have a button there. A button is not an anchor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a button with a `href` and `a` attribute, not an `a` element. If you want your button to act as a link to `https://.../#dos`, try this instead:

```
<button onclick="location.hash='dos'">Go to /#dos</button>
```

Comment: Perfect! It worked.